# Logical Equivalence x can fool y

Tags: logic

Let F(x,y) mean x can fool y

There is exactly one person who everybody can fool:
∃y(∀xF(x,y))^∀z(∀wF(w,z)) -> y=z

How would I say exactly one person who nobody can fool?

Comment: Can you not use the notation  ∃! to mean there exists a unique element?  Much simpler than the "^∀z(∀wF(w,z)) -> y=z" business.  If you don't have that, you can define E!a(P) = Ea(P)^∀z(P)->z=a once for all properties P and use it from hereon out.  It makes things easier.

Comment: We can't use that notation.

Comment: no problem.  We can do the "^∀z(P)->z=a" jazz till the cows come home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody can fool a: ∀x(-F(x,a)

There exists somebody nobody can fool:∃a(∀x-F(x,a))

She is unique: ∃a(∀x-F(x,a))^∀z(∀x-F(x,z)) -> z=a